# SVG img on the same line of text in inline-block container

Tags: html, css, svg

How can i have my SVG image on the same line of my text in an inline-block container ?

In the above example, I want my picture let at the right of my text, on the same line but browser automaticaly break line.

```css
.container{
  display: inline-block;
  background:orange;
}
```

```html
<div class=container>
text<img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/aquis/image/upload/v1521481254/site-2018/megaphone-picto.svg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply specify a width and/or a height to the image:

```css
.container{
  display: inline-block;
  background:orange;
}
```

```html
<div class=container>
text<img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/aquis/image/upload/v1521481254/site-2018/megaphone-picto.svg" width="20">
</div>
```

Comment: I don't whant to set static height or width because it's administrable content. any otheer solution ?

Comment: @Fabien it's an external SVG --> it means that it's scalable --> it means that if you don't define any width/height the browser will do it for you. It's not like an image where you can use it without any width/height because it has inner width/height .... here it's about SVG

Answer (score 1):

Remove `display: inline-block` from your `.container` class and set the `inline-block` on your image. Since it is an `svg`, you will also want to give the `svg` an explicit height and width.

It's recommended to wrap the `img` in a `span` tag, instead of setting it to the `img` html element, which would set the same small size on all image items on your site. I gave the span the classname of `svg-image`, but you could name it anything else.

```css
.container{
  background:orange;
}

.svg-image {
 display: inline-block; 
 height:20px; 
 width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class=container>
text<span class="svg-image"><img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/aquis/image/upload/v1521481254/site-2018/megaphone-picto.svg"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Why span? figure

Comment: I don't whant to set static height or width because it's administrable content. any otheer solution ?