# SVG img inline with a multi line text "block"

Tags: html, css, svg, inline-styles

My question is principally similar to this one: [SVG img on the same line of text in inline-block container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49369858/svg-img-on-the-same-line-of-text-in-inline-block-container)

I have a SVG image, which I want to build into the text, which "displaces" the text from the left side. The text is at least two lines long and it's a `<h1>` if it matters.

What I've tried to far:

- Set the height and/or width just like in that question
- Wrapping it in a paragraph (`<p>`)
- Wrapping it in a div with a specified width and/or height
- According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/64892423 I tried to add `justify-self: start;` - has no effect as well...

How do I solve this primitive problem? Help is appreciated.

```html
<div class=company-content>
<p>
<div style="width:10%; height:10%; display:inline-grid;">
<img src="graphics/filenamehere.svg" style=" display:inline-flex; height:3rem;" /> 
</div>
<h1>Lorem Ipsum Text here</h1>
</p>
```

## UPDATE

Minimal reproducable example:

```js
/* Add a random picture */
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = 'https://unsplash.it/200/300/?random';
document.body.appendChild(img);

/* Add some lorem ipsum text next to  the picture */
var lorem = document.createElement('div');
lorem.innerHTML = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam euismod, nunc eget euismod tincidunt, nunc nisi tincidunt augue, nec consectetur nunc nisi eu nunc. Nullam eget nunc eu nisl sagittis porttitor. Nullam euismod, nunc eget euismod tincidunt, nunc nisi tincidunt augue, nec consectetur nunc nisi eu nunc. Nullam eget nunc eu nisl sagittis porttitor.';
document.body.appendChild(lorem);

/* Make the picture sit on the left side of the text inline with the text */
img.style.float = 'left';

/* Make the text a h1 header */
lorem.style.fontSize = '1.5em';
lorem.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
```

This works, but not in my code, which uses a h1 tag...

## UPDATE 2

My not properly working code:

```css
.company-content {
    width: 79%;
    display: inline-grid;
    /*margin-left: 75px;*/
}
```

```html
<div class=company-content>
  <p>
    <div style="width:10%; height:10%; display:inline-grid; float:left;"><img src="https://picsum.photos/500" style=" display:flex; width:3rem; height:3rem; align-items:center; float:left;" /> </div>Lorem Ipsum blablabla bla bla bla bla</p>
```

Comment: @RobertLongson I added a HTML and CSS snippet.

Comment: The paragraph element seems pretty superfluous. (Plus, you did not actually _wrap_ anything into it, with that code - `p` can not contain `div`, so the browser will close the `p` as soon as it encounters the `div`.) Just float the image ...? If that doesn't do the job, then please give a better explanation of what this is actually supposed to look like.

Comment: @CBroe my bad, forgot to add the closing tag into the question, but the browser still interprets it as a standalone paragraph and it is not enclosed correctly. I tried using float, it apparently did nothing as well... I'll add a picture soon.

Comment: @CBroe I did a minimal reproduction of the code (yes, made it *even* more simple) and as long as I don't use the h1 tag the float:left works fine. Any clue how to fix this?

Comment: A "minimal reproducable example" that doesn't actually manage to reproduce the problem to begin with, is pretty pointless.

Comment: If I had to _guess_ (which questions asked here should not force us to do), then I'd say you probably have `clear` applied to the headline.

Comment: @CBroe I have no `clear` applied to the h1 tag, unless that's the default value if you specify nothing. I updated the question

Comment: You can not mix float and grid like that. Use one, or the other.

Comment: How do I implement a grid solution for it then? That would be an answer that I would upvote and select as the answer if it solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for image and text same line for your requirement.

```html
<div class=company-content>
        <p>
            <div style="width:60%; height:10%; display:flex; align-items: center;    justify-content: center;
margin: 0 auto;">
                <img src="graphics/filenamehere.svg" />
                <h1 style="margin: 0;">Lorem Ipsum Text here</h1>
            </div>
        </p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Apparently doesn't work as intended. It looks the same as if there we no styling rules (the img is above the text). It should also not be centered in the middle, but at the left side, but that's easy to fix.